# Livewire Not rendering data if loading a clicked function

Tags: laravel-livewire

There is any way to write code in livewire that if I submit a click command with a button then the livewire componant page rendering even the clicked function is loading. Because now I see that not loading the other data on the livewire page when livewire funciton loading.

Answer (score 0):

If the click function takes longer, then maybe a Laravel Job can do that, otherwise Livewire waits for the whole cycle to complete https://calebporzio.com/how-livewire-works-a-deep-dive